# How to put out a Dos screen once you build in Visual studio?

Tags: c++, build

I'm pretty new to programming and I have built my program a few times. However I can't figure out how to make a Command Window or DOS window show up, even after the build has finished in Visual Studio on Windows.

Comment: Did you try the "play" button? Building does not automatically run the application. It's also not "dos" but "command line"

Comment: Note that older versions of Visual Studio default to closing the console window as soon as the program ends. Often this happens so fast that you don't see that the program ran at all. Pop a breakpoint on the closing brace of `main` and the program will stop at the breakpoint and let you read the output. When your done, let the program continue running. I think that's the F5 key, but I'm using too many different IDEs right now to be 100% sure of the hotkeys.

Comment: If the program never reaches the end of `main`, put the breakpoint at the beginning of `main` and step through the program line by line to see where it exits prematurely.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have built your program as a 'Console app' or 'Command-Line app' in Visual Studio. These were choices you made when you first set up your project. Then, running your program from Visual Studio will cause a Command Window (DOS like) to display, and your program will start within this window.

The 'Debug' menu item has 'Start Debugging' and 'Start Without Debugging' - either choice will run your program.

Depending on your version of Visual Studio or your configuration options, Visual Studio may close the console window as soon as the program completes. This is not the default behavior on recent Visual Studio options, but you may miss the Console Window popping up and going away if it is happening to you. Likewise, it may be hidden if the Console Window is not displayed as the top-most Window.